# Spark YARN capacity scheduler

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

I am trying to setup capacity scheduler in Amazon EMR with 2 queues in addition to the default queue. I have successfully created the queues user1 and user2, however when I use spark-submit to run a script on a new queue it will get stuck in ACCEPTED. The weird thing is that I can still submit applications to the default queue and everything works as expected.

Currently using the Default scheduler, but I have tried using the Dominant scheduler with the same results.

I have looked at the logs and they mostly look okay. Sometimes I will get the an error:

`2019-12-04 19:18:28,888 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.LeafQueue (ResourceManager Event Processor): maximum-am-resource-percent is insufficient to start a single application in queue, it is likely set too low. skipping enforcement to allow at least one application to start`

Although I have maximum-am-resource-percent set to 100% (I think.) I have also tried setting this property explicitly for every queue with no success.

How I am running the job:

`spark-submit --master yarn --queue user1 test.py`

The number of running (healthy) task/core nodes doesn't seem to make a difference.

I'm new to managing Spark, so any guidance would be appreciated. I haven't been able to find much online other than responses stating there are no resources available. My configuration may very well not allocate enough resources, but I don't think this would be the case if the default queue still works fine. Here is my capacity-scheduler.xml for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!--
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License. See accompanying LICENSE file.
-->
<configuration>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-applications</name>
    <value>10000</value>
    <description>
      Maximum number of applications that can be pending and running.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-am-resource-percent</name>
    <value>1.0</value>
    <description>
      Maximum percent of resources in the cluster which can be used to run
      application masters i.e. controls number of concurrent running
      applications.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DefaultResourceCalculator</value>
    <description>
      The ResourceCalculator implementation to be used to compare
      Resources in the scheduler.
      The default i.e. DefaultResourceCalculator only uses Memory while
      DominantResourceCalculator uses dominant-resource to compare
      multi-dimensional resources such as Memory, CPU etc.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.queues</name>
    <value>user1,user2,default</value>
    <description>
      The queues at the this level (root is the root queue).
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.capacity</name>
    <value>10</value>
    <description>Default queue target capacity.</description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.user-limit-factor</name>
    <value>2</value>
    <description>
      Default queue user limit a percentage from 0.0 to 1.0.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.maximum-capacity</name>
    <value>40</value>
    <description>
      The maximum capacity of the default queue.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.state</name>
    <value>RUNNING</value>
    <description>
      The state of the default queue. State can be one of RUNNING or STOPPED.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.acl_submit_applications</name>
    <value>*</value>
    <description>
      The ACL of who can submit jobs to the default queue.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.acl_administer_queue</name>
    <value>*</value>
    <description>
      The ACL of who can administer jobs on the default queue.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.node-locality-delay</name>
    <value>40</value>
    <description>
      Number of missed scheduling opportunities after which the CapacityScheduler
      attempts to schedule rack-local containers.
      Typically this should be set to number of nodes in the cluster, By default is setting
      approximately number of nodes in one rack which is 40.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.queue-mappings</name>
    <value />
    <description>
      A list of mappings that will be used to assign jobs to queues
      The syntax for this list is [u|g]:[name]:[queue_name][,next mapping]*
      Typically this list will be used to map users to queues,
      for example, u:%user:%user maps all users to queues with the same name
      as the user.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.queue-mappings-override.enable</name>
    <value>false</value>
    <description>
      If a queue mapping is present, will it override the value specified
      by the user? This can be used by administrators to place jobs in queues
      that are different than the one specified by the user.
      The default is false.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.per-node-heartbeat.maximum-offswitch-assignments</name>
    <value>1</value>
    <description>
      Controls the number of OFF_SWITCH assignments allowed
      during a node's heartbeat. Increasing this value can improve
      scheduling rate for OFF_SWITCH containers. Lower values reduce
      "clumping" of applications on particular nodes. The default is 1.
      Legal values are 1-MAX_INT. This config is refreshable.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.accessible-node-labels</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.accessible-node-labels.CORE.capacity</name>
    <value>100</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.accessible-node-labels</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.accessible-node-labels.CORE.capacity</name>
    <value>100</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.user1.capacity</name>
    <value>50</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.user1.user-limit-factor</name>
    <value>2</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.user1.maximum-capacity</name>
    <value>50</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.user2.capacity</name>
    <value>40</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.user2.user-limit-factor</name>
    <value>2</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.user2.maximum-capacity</name>
    <value>50</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.user1.state</name>
    <value>RUNNING</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.user2.state</name>
    <value>RUNNING</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.user1.acl_submit_applications</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.user2.acl_submit_applications</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Thanks,
Seth

Answer (score 1):

Starting with version 5.19.0, EMR uses YARN node labels for the different node groups (`MASTER` / `CORE` / `TASK`) [1]. In order for custom queues to work correctly in this setup, you need to explicitly configure the mapping between queues and node labels.

If you look at the `capacity-scheduler.xml`, you'll notice that EMR has already configured this for you for the `root` and `default` queues:

```
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.accessible-node-labels</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.accessible-node-labels.CORE.capacity</name>
    <value>100</value>
  </property>
```

This is why running an application on the `default` queue works correctly.

So to get your custom queues working, you'll have to set their `accessible-node-labels` and `capacity` settings. You should be able to use the same `capacity` settings as in the rest of your queue config.

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-master-core-task-nodes.html